# angular/cli reports 'this.tree.readText is not a function' when trying to generate a new component

Tags: angular-cli, angular-eslint

When I try to get angular/cli to generate a new component for me all it does is print the message

```
this.tree.readText is not a function
```

and exits.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and using `ng` in a console window.
I am trying to generate a new component in a feature module. I am starting `ng` in the feature-module directory with the following command:

```
ng g c components/my-new-component --change-detection OnPush
```

The working directory is similar to:

```
~/Develop/my-project/src/app/feature-module
```

and I'm expecting four new files to be generated in the new folder

```
~/Develop/my-project/src/app/feature-module/components/my-new-component/
```

as well as the module file

```
~/Develop/my-project/src/app/feature-module/feature-module.module.ts
```

to be updated with the newly generated component.

I'm also getting this behavior on Ubunut 20.04.
A colleague has the same problem on his Mac (an M1) when using `ng` on the command line, but is not really hampered as he uses IntelliJ and has an extension for generateing new components, rather than using the command line.

I've tried googling the problem without any success. I've also tried deleting node_modules along with the package-lock.json file and reinstalling all packages but to no avail.

I'm using the following node/typescript/angular versions:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 13.3.8
Node: 14.19.2
Package Manager: npm 6.14.17
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.3.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.8
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.3
@angular/cdk                    13.3.9
@angular/cli                    13.3.8
@angular/material               13.3.9
@schematics/angular             14.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.5.5
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried creating a new project, adding a feature module and adding a component to the feature module - everything worked perfectly, so I suppose the problem is being caused by something in the project (or its structure) I'm working on. This is going to be fun...

Comment: Do you have jQuery installed?

Comment: @Vega No. Why do you ask?

Comment: A quick research was pointing to some missing jQuery packages. Just to clear that out

Comment: It looks like there have been a bug report about 1.5 months ago https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23072

Comment: @Vega Thank you for looking - I also found that report, but discounted it, as it applies to v14 and has been automatically closed due to inactivity. I find it very weird that this error occurs on three different machines, but doesn't seem to be happening to anyone else. On the other hand although I tested it on the three different machines, I used the same project - which might be the cause of the problem...I'm going to test that now.

Comment: I think it is version incompatibility issu. On those machines the older installation exist? n all clean from scractch installation may be necessary

Comment: @Vega I found the problem - in the angular.json file there's an optional section `cli` for project specific cli options. During the migration from tslint to eslint this section was added with the property `defaultCollection` set to `"@angular-eslint/schematics"`. In the documentation for angular 13 this option wasn't listed, `schematicCollections` is though. Replacing `defaultCollection` with `schematicCollections` did the trick. Unfortunately the JSON-schema for angular.json specifies `defaultCollection` and not `schematicCollections`, so my IDE (vs code) sees a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ng was exiting unexpectedly with only the message

```
this.tree.readText is not a function
```

so I went looking for `this.tree.readText` in the code. It seems only to be used in the @schematics package in conjuction with reading and writing the workspace. Following the suggestion by @Vega that it might be a version incompatibility issue I checked what was in `angular.json` against the online documentation - during the project we've continually upgraded from version 8 to 13.

There was a difference: at the end of the file was the following:

```
"cli": {
  "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
}
```

This was added during the migration from TSLint to ESLint. We used the angular-eslint schematic to carry out the migration:

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics

ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint
```

but I'm not sure anymore if this line was added automatically or whether we added the line afterwards.

In the online documentation for the [Angular Workspace Configuration (cli options)](https://v13.angular.io/guide/workspace-config#cli-configuration-options) there's no mention of `defaultCollection`, but there is a `schematicCollections`. By replacing the cli-options with this:

```
"cli": {
  "schematicCollections": ["@angular-eslint/schematics"]
}
```

`ng generate` started working again. Interestingly enough the JSON-schema for the `angular.json` file specifies the property `defaultCollection` but not `schematicCollections`.

Comment: This is clear and solved my problem direct. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 10):

Bonjour, so I had the same issue as you have in my Ionic Angular Project and looked for days without finding a clear answer to my problem.

However your answer lead me to my solution.
For me my `angular.json` was also configured like this

```json
"cli": {
  "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
}
```

and it didn't allow me to change it to `schematicCollections`.
The solution for me ended up being downgrading my `@ionic/angular-toolkit` from version 7.0.0 to 6.1.0.

Comment: On my side I had to upgrade to 6.1.0. I had previously upgraded my app from ionic 5 angular 7 to ionic 6 angular 9. Somehow, that brought incompatibility with the version that was there for @ionic/angular-toolkit (2.3.3).

Comment: I had  @ionic/angular-toolkit version 7 in dev dependencies and "@ionic/angular": "^6.3.2" in dependencies, this caused the error

Comment: I had the same problem

 `"cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
  },`

It worked for me by just removing this line `"defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"` and run the generate new component command. I will re-upgrade/fix the packages soon so I thought it could be a temp. solution

Answer (score 3):

Thanks!
Your solution worked to me too. But in this case for my was in:

```
"cli": {
"schematicCollections": "@ionic/angular-toolkit",
```

Comment: can you share your angular.json file?

Answer (score 3):

This problem happened to me when I tried to add service workers to my app using Angular's Progressive Web App (PWA) capability. I naïvely ran `ng add @angular/pwa`, but my global Angular CLI version was newer than my project's Angular version. That means the `@angular/pwa` version was too new for my Angular project, which caused the error message that this question describes.

Here's how I solved it:

1. Run `npm remove @angular/pwa`.
2. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/pwa?activeTab=versions to find the correct version number for your project. The **Tag** field tells you the Angular version to which the package version corresponds.
3. Run `ng add` again for the correct version. For example, run `npm add @angular/pwa@0.803` for an old Angular 8 project.

Answer (score 2):

I had an older copy of the angular cli installed in my local project (13.0.1) that was overriding the global version (14.2.5).  Removed the local project version and worked.

```
npm uninstall    "@angular/cli" --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
"app": {
"root": "",
"sourceRoot": "src",
"projectType": "application",
"prefix": "app",
"schematics": {},
"architect": {
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
"outputPath": "www",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts",
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"assets": [
{
"glob": "**/*",
"input": "src/assets",
"output": "assets"
},
{
"glob": "**/*.svg",
"input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
"output": "./svg"
}
],
"styles": [
"src/theme/variables.scss",
"src/global.scss"
],
"scripts": [],
"aot": false,
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"buildOptimizer": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"optimization": false,
"namedChunks": true
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"fileReplacements": [
{
"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
],
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
"budgets": [
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "2mb",
"maximumError": "5mb"
}
]
},
"ci": {
"progress": false
}
}
},
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "app:build"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"browserTarget": "app:build:production"
},
"ci": {
"progress": false
}
}
},
"extract-i18n": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "app:build"
}
},
"test": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
"options": {
"main": "src/test.ts",
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
"karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
"styles": [],
"scripts": [],
"assets": [
{
"glob": "favicon.ico",
"input": "src/",
"output": "/"
},
{
"glob": "**/*",
"input": "src/assets",
"output": "/assets"
}
]
},
"configurations": {
"ci": {
"progress": false,
"watch": false
}
}
},
"lint": {
"builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
"options": {
"lintFilePatterns": [
"src/**/*.ts",
"src/**/*.html"
]
}
},
"e2e": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
"options": {
"protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
"devServerTarget": "app:serve"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
},
"ci": {
"devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
}
}
},
"ionic-cordova-serve": {
"builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-serve",
"options": {
"cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
"devServerTarget": "app:serve"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
"devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
}
}
},
"ionic-cordova-build": {
"builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-build",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "app:build"
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"browserTarget": "app:build:production"
}
}
}
}
}
},
"cli": {
"schematicCollections": [
"@ionic/angular-toolkit"
],
"analytics": "e312721c-a7d5-4f36-99b4-b0f94f4ee24d"
},
"schematics": {
"@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
"styleext": "scss"
},
"@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
"styleext": "scss"
}
}
}
```

`

try reemplace angular.json work for my, try and diff for check diferences and analize this json

Answer (score 0):

In my case needed only update @angular/cli package in project as others angular packages